# Flutter Secure Storage Issues: Unable to read or write keys and values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using this package to store some login credentials in a Flutter mobile application. The version I use is **v5.0.2**. I am not sure if I am storing or reading the value in the correct way. Does anyone know how to check it, or what am I missing or doing wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  Future<Map<String, String>> _readAll() async {
    return await _storage.readAll(
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(), aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
  }

  void deleteAll() async {
    await _storage.deleteAll(
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(), aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
    _readAll();
  }

  Future<String?> readSecureData(String key) async {
    return await _storage.read(key: key);
  }

  Future<void> deleteSecureData(String key) async {
    return await _storage.delete(key: key);
  }

  void writeSecureData(String key, String value) async {
    await _storage.write(
      key: key,
      value: value,
      iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
      aOptions: _getAndroidOptions(),
    );
  }

  IOSOptions _getIOSOptions() => const IOSOptions(
        accessibility: IOSAccessibility.first_unlock,
      );

  AndroidOptions _getAndroidOptions() => const AndroidOptions(
        encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
      );
}

final secureStorage = SecureStorage();
```

This is how I called the value,

```
@override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      final username = await secureStorage.readSecureData('username') ?? '';
      final password = await secureStorage.readSecureData('password') ?? '';
      setState(() {
        _icNoController.text = username;
        _passwordController.text = password;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

And this is how I stored the value,

```
await secureStorage.writeSecureData('username', username);
await secureStorage.writeSecureData('password', password);
```

Comment: You cannot call `setState` in `initState`. Also I suggest you wrap all calls to SecureStorage in a `try-catch` block. It caused me hard to find bugs when I didn't do that initially.

Comment: did you fix this problem? I am facing the same problem @KeroJohn97

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason for reading / writing problem can be inconsistency with using `aOptions` or `iOptions`. 
For ex. you are using `aOptions` with `readAll()`, `deleateAll()` and `write()` methods and you don't use it with `read()`, `delete()`. 
So, when using `encryptedSharedPreferences: true,` in `aOptions` when you write data to secure storage, you specify that this data must be written to `EncryptedSharedPreferences`. 
However when you read the data without providing aOptions again, you try to read from default secure storage which is not the EncryptedSharedPreferences where you have stored the data.
Example with `aOptions` is for Android, I haven't tested this library on iOS yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned up the class for you:

```
class SecureStorage {
  const _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  Future<Map<String, String>> _readAll() async {
    var map = <String, String>{};
    try {
      map = await _storage.readAll(
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
        aOptions: _getAndroidOptions(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return map;
  }

  Future<void> deleteAll() async {
    try {
      await _storage.deleteAll(
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
        aOptions: _getAndroidOptions(),
      );
      // _readAll();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<String> readSecureData(String key) async {
    String value = "";
    try {
      value = (await _storage.read(key: key)) ?? "";
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return value;
  }

  Future<void> deleteSecureData(String key) async {
    try {
      await _storage.delete(key: key);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> writeSecureData(String key, String value) async {
    try {
      await _storage.write(
        key: key,
        value: value,
        iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
        aOptions: _getAndroidOptions(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  IOSOptions _getIOSOptions() => const IOSOptions(
    accessibility: IOSAccessibility.first_unlock,
  );

  AndroidOptions _getAndroidOptions() => const AndroidOptions(
    encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
  );
}
```

Of course, I use a `Logger` package instead of `print`. Also I don't understand why you do a `_readAll` after `deleteAll`.

**ANSWERS**

Q. "I am not sure if I am storing or reading the value in the correct way."

A. The correct way to store and read the values are by wrapping them in a `try-catch` block, as illustrated the code above.

Q. "Does anyone know how to check it, or what am I missing or doing wrong."

A. See the code above for example of how to do it the right way which I personally found works for me.

Comment: You did not answer the question.@Roslan Amir

Comment: Sorry. I will try to answer the exact questions asked. Even though I don't see any question marks anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are using `const` in your getters, I think maybe it will be better if you just throw the const options into the `FlutterSecureStorage` constructor , like:

```
final _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage(
  iOptions: IOSOptions(accessibility: KeychainAccessibility.first_unlock),
  aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true),
);
```